# Can't access hardware info of remote computer with WMI: Access is denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to create an application that uses WMI to retrieve information about a computer on my local network. When I run it, I get an access denied error. Here is the code:

```
 private void GetHDDdetails()
{
    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
    options.Username = "username";
    options.Password = "password";
    options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    ManagementScope oMs = new ManagementScope("\\\\remoteHostName\\root\\cimv2", options);
    ObjectQuery oQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT Size FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
    ManagementObjectSearcher oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oMs, oQuery);
    ManagementObjectCollection oCollection = oSearcher.Get();


    foreach (ManagementObject obj in oCollection)
    {
        hddBox.Text = obj["Size"].ToString();
    }
}
```

I have replaced some of the info above, such as user name and password, with placeholders for this post.
Some of the things I have tried is this: Disabling firewall on both machines, making sure TCP NetBIOS service and RCP and WMI services are running on both. The account I am using is an administrator on the local computer. Everything I have found online tells me to check these, but it is obviously something else.
If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Please check using **wbemtest** that you can access the information from remote machine. And i hope you are replacing `remoteHostName` properly.
And make changes to authentication level, if you can.

```
scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
scope.Options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
```